# How to use the names_to argument in pivot_longer()

Tags: r, tidyverse

I've seen a couple of other similar questions here on SO on the names_to argument; however, I'm still not sure I understand how to use it.

Consider the below df:

```
df <- data.frame("Metric" = c("a_exp_2001","a_inc_2001","a_inc_2002","a_exp_2002"),
                "John" = c(220,230,240,250),
                "Abby" = c(440,450,470,480))

head(df)

      Metric John Abby
1 a_exp_2001  220  440
2 a_inc_2001  230  450
3 a_inc_2002  240  470
4 a_exp_2002  250  480
```

I'm looking to create a new data frame that has the above information for only one year (say 2002) but in long format. That is, I want to end up with 3 columns "Names","Expenditure" (where values correspond to `a_exp_2002`),"Income" (where values correspond to `a_inc_2002`).

I'm not sure how to specify the `names_to` argument in `pivot_longer()` to get to that final df.

I've only been able to get so far:

```
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -c(Metric), ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do the job?

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble::tribble(
         ~Metric.John.Abby,
  "1 a_exp_2001  220  440",
  "2 a_inc_2001  230  450",
  "3 a_inc_2002  240  470",
  "4 a_exp_2002  250  480"
  ) %>% 
  tidyr::separate("Metric.John.Abby", into = c('num', 'metric', 'sp', 'john', 'sp2', 'abby'), sep = " ") %>% 
  select(metric, john, abby) 

data %>% 
  filter(str_detect(metric, "2002")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -metric, names_to = "names") %>% 
  separate(metric, into = c('letter', 'type', 'year')) %>% 
  select(type, names, value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(type, id_cols = c('type', 'names')) %>% 
  relocate(exp, .before = inc)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   names exp   inc  
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 john  250   240  
#> 2 abby  480   470
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly this would be a possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame("Metric" = c("a_exp_2001","a_inc_2001","a_inc_2002","a_exp_2002"),
                 "John" = c(220,230,240,250),
                 "Abby" = c(440,450,470,480))

df %>% 
  # get relevant info from Metric in two columns
  dplyr::mutate(IN_or_EX =  substr(Metric, start = 3, stop = 5),
                YEAR = substr(Metric, start = 7, stop = 10)) %>% 
  # filter for the year you wan
  dplyr::filter(YEAR == 2001) %>% 
  # drop the Metric column as it presents no value anymore
  dplyr::select(-Metric) %>%
  # make it longer
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(IN_or_EX, YEAR), names_to = "NAME", values_to = "VALUES") %>% 
  # make it wider
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = IN_or_EX, values_from = VALUES, values_fill = 0)


  YEAR  NAME    exp   inc
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2001  Abby    440   450
2 2001  John    220   230
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for:

```r
pivot_longer(df, -1) %>% 
  separate(Metric, sep = 6, into = c("type", "year")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = value) %>%
  rename(Expenditure = a_exp_, Income = a_inc_)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   year  name  Expenditure Income
#>   <chr> <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 2001  John          220    230
#> 2 2001  Abby          440    450
#> 3 2002  John          250    240
#> 4 2002  Abby          480    470
```